# How to return Multiple Objects in LINQ - asp.net mvc 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am stuck here with Linq query... I am just trying to get my hands on MVC via this very simple blog application.. I am hving these three entities

Post,
AuthorDetails,
CommentsDetails, //* in future will be adding categories, tags

i want to search using the searchterm passed into the methods, which will then search for that searchString in Post.Title, Post.Body,AuthorDetails.FirstName,AuthorDetails.LastName,CommentsDetails.Comments and waht to return something which i can cast to List<> ...please have a look what i have got so far.

## Code..

```
 public List<Post> GetPostBySearchItem(string searchString)
        {
            List<Post> getAllPostsBySearchString = (from p in ePost.Posts
                                                    join a in ePost.AuthorDetails
                                                    on p.AuthorId equals a.Id
                                                    join c in ePost.CommentsDetails
                                                    on a.Id equals c.Id
                                                    where p.Title.Contains(searchString) || p.PostBody.Contains(searchString) || a.FirstName.Contains(searchString) || c.Comments.Contains(searchString)
                                                    select p).ToList();
            return getAllPostsBySearchString;
```

2 question here
1) whether the join statements are correct in this code
2) and how can i return something like this select P for Posts, A for AuthoreDetails and c for CommentsDetails...

Comment: Not an answer to your question directly, but it seems like you are trying to add search capability to your site... I would highly recommend looking at Lucene for .Net to add such functionality.   You can find an example here http://www.ifdefined.com/blog/post/2009/02/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx

Comment: Is there a reason you're using joins rather than associations here? If you establish associations from Post to Comments/Authors/Categories/etc, you could return List<Post> and navigate to the children in your view assuming you eager load the children appropriatly. Sounds like you're going through much of the same thing I did with www.ThinqLinq.com. You're free to check out my source in the file downloads at [link](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Files.aspx).

Comment: @jim: i will surely have a look at it... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question #2: you simply have to return with "new" like this:

```
select new { Post = p, AuthorDetail = a, CommentDetail = c}).ToList()
```

instead of:

```
select p).ToList();
```

Look up [Anonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

Comment: Thx... i have tried that and tried again ...its simply giving me the error " Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcMBlog1.Models.Post>'

Comment: the problem is here.. what should i  do here .... 
List<Post> getAllPostsBySearchString .. i have also tried var.. just to let you know...

Comment: Yes, because your return type is List<Post>. According your question was "how can I return something like..." that would be anonymous type, and you can't return a Post. The only other way you can do it is top have the AuthorDetail and CommentDetail within the Post object. Then your return type will work. Check the example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

Comment: thats great... works fine... just to confirm my LINQ joins are fine ?